# dynamics crm 365 plugin delay between execution pipeline stages

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Our plugin is running slow on the "Retrieve" message, so I placed a few timestamps in the code to determine where the bottle neck is. I realized there is a 7 second delay which happens intermittently between the end of the pre-operation stage and the start of the post operation stage.

END PRE - 3/22/2018 11:57:55 AM
POST STAGE START - 3/22/2018 11:58:02 AM

```
protected virtual void RetrievePreOperation()
{
    var message = $"END PRE - {DateTime.Now}";
    PluginExecutionContext.SharedVariables.Add("message", message);
}

protected virtual void RetrievePostOperation()
{
     // Stop recursive calls
     if (PluginExecutionContext.Depth > 1) return;

     if (PluginExecutionContext.MessageName.ToLower() != Retrieve ||
         !PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters.Contains("Target") ||
         PluginExecutionContext.Stage != (int)PipelineStages.PostOperation)
         return;


    var entity = (Entity)PluginExecutionContext.OutputParameters["BusinessEntity"];

    string message = PluginExecutionContext.SharedVariables["message"].ToString();
    message += $"POST STAGE START - {DateTime.Now}";             
}
```

Any ideas on how to minimize this delay would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the Post Retrieve plugin step registered as asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your plugin step is registered on Asynchronous execution mode, this delay totally depends on Async service load & pipeline of waiting calls/jobs. You can switch it to Synchronous.

If its registered in Synchronous mode but still delay is there intermittently, it depends on many things like which entity, query & complex logic if any.